# How to handle former global event handlers in ASP.NET 5?

Tags: asp.net, owin

Actually, we use ASP.NET 4.5 (VS 2013) and want to replace Global.asax.cs with new Startup.cs file, which comes from OWIN specification.

We log the start and the end of application using Application_Start and Application_End handlers in this way:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _log.Info("The app starts.");
}

protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _log.Info("The app ends.");
}
```

But, as I know there is no such handlers in the new Startup.cs file. So, my question is - how can we do that?

Comment: You already know when the application is starting since Startup.cs is executing then. For the application end event have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444924/is-there-application-end-from-global-asax-in-owin

Comment: It works. Thanks. And do you happen to know what to do with Session_Start and Session_End?

Comment: OK. If you write your answer as regular post, I'll checked it out.

Comment: Alright, I dont know about the session events though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know when the application is starting since Startup.cs is executing then. For the `Application_End` event have a look at this answer: [Is there Application_End from Global.asax in Owin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444924/is-there-application-end-from-global-asax-in-owin)